# Failing oozie launcher on yarn-cluster mode

Tags: hadoop, jar, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, oozie

so I'm trying to run a spark job on yarn-cluster mode (succeeded running it in local mode and yarn-client), but I am running into a problem where oozie launcher fails. Below is the error message from `stderr`.

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain], main() threw exception, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.byteStringAsBytes(Ljava/lang/String;)J
org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMainException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.byteStringAsBytes(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:60)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:46)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runSubtask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runTask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.access$200(LocalContainerLauncher.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler$1.run(LocalContainerLauncher.java:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.byteStringAsBytes(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.memoryStringToMb(Utils.scala:993)
    at org.apache.spark.util.MemoryParam$.unapply(MemoryParam.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientArguments.parseArgs(ClientArguments.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientArguments.<init>(ClientArguments.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:966)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:57)
    ... 19 more
```

The job runs on spark 1.5.2, so I downloaded and put the `spark-assembly-1.5.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar` file onto HDFS, and set the `spark.yarn.jar` field in my spark config file to point to the jar path, and set the `oozie.libpath` field in my job.properties file to point to the directory in which the jar resides.

I searched for other possible versions of Spark in the classpath section in the `stdout` log, and found two instances where `spark-1.3.0-cdh5.4.5-yarn-shuffle.jar` was being picked up (fortunately, `spark-assembly-1.5.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar` is being picked up elsewhere too so I am setting the path correctly).

So, the problem seems to be that oozie, or oozie launcher is defaulting to use spark 1.3 for some reason (which is installed on the system that the job is trying to run on). I tried setting the `oozie.use.system.libpath` field to false in the job.properties file, but it doesn't seem to have helped. Any ideas on what I can to do prevent spark 1.3 from being picked up, or any other solutions that can solve the NoSuchMethodError I am facing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What was the location for "spark-1.3" jar -- in the container "root dir" (i.e. issued from an Oozie package or from a `<file>` instruction in your action) or in a subdirectory (typically a symlink to the pre-installed Hadoop client lib)?

Comment: And anyway I believe you **need** the `spark-yarn-shuffle` jar in addition to your `spark-assembly`; and in the same version if possible.

Comment: Back to the CLASSPATH precedence topic -- try to set both properties `oozie.launcher.mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first` and `mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first` to `true` to make sure that Oozie libs and your action-defined libs have precedence over Hadoop libs. And check that the rogue Spark 1.3 libs did not slip into the Oozie ShareLibs (under `hdfs:///user/oozie/share/lib/` typically)