# how to add classpath to oozie java action with sharedlib and external jars

Tags: classpath, oozie

I have a java application which needs the library of hadoop, hdfs, hive and spark, also some external libraries,
I've read [this page](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-use-the-sharelib-in-apache-oozie/) but I'm still confused about the order of overriding sharedlib,
in the job configure, I have

```
oozie.use.system.libpath=false
oozie.action.sharelib.for.java=spark,hive2,hive
```

I also put the external jars under the /lib of the workspace directory.

Now I got this problem, in my jar I used class from `json4s-native`, so I put them in the `myworkspace/lib` path, but under the `oozie/share/lib/spark`,also has library of `json4s-jackson`, after a run the java action, throw an error of 
    `Launcher exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json4s/native/JsonMethods$`

How can I get oozie use the library in my `/lib` path first?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. Cf.my comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381688/make-oozie-do-not-change-classpath-of-java-action and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478748/email-from-oozie-java-jobs and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346013/failing-oozie-launcher-on-yarn-cluster-mode

Comment: So the easy option would be to compile your code against the same exact deps that Spark uses -- no more custom JAR, no more conflict. Another option would be to build your own custom "private lib", by hand-picking JARs from the Spark and Hive "share libs"; but that's a trial-and-error process and you have no guarantee that Spark will accept another JSON implementation!